# transitting between terminals in Cairo

Tags: transit, airport-terminals, cairo

My flight itinerary consists of the following routes: Johannesburg to Cairo + Cairo to Casablanca. Both routes are operated by Egyptair. I understand these two routes operate in different terminals (2 and 3).

My question is: Is it possible to transfer between terminals airside, without clearing customs and immigration. This itinerary is ticketed as one ticket with a 2 hour 30 mins transit in Cairo. I cannot find this transit information online.

Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, it's possible.** Cairo Airport has an
airside people-mover ("Mini Metro") connecting Terminals 2 and 3, and since both your flights are on Egyptair, any baggage you have will be checked through.

Disclaimer: I have no personal experience of this transfer (T2 only opened in 2017), and it's possible but unlikely that there are still some COVID shenanigans that make life harder.